# Improving perfomance for randomly created panels

Tags: c#, performance, random, panel

So what I'm trying to do is create like a random image from panels of different colors. The user can choose how many panels (i.e. pixels) he wants to have and the number of different colors and then the program automatically generates that image. I'd really like to use panels for this because I will need this picture later on and need to modify every single pixel. As I'm comfortable with panels, I'd like to keep them and not use anything else.

So here's the code I'm using to create this panels:

```
//Creates two lists of panels
        //Add items to list so that these places in the list can be used later.
        //nudSizeX.Value is the user-chosen number of panels in x-direction
        for (int a = 0; a < nudSizeX.Value; a++)
        {
            horizontalRows.Add(null);
        }
        //nudSizeY.Value is the user-chosen number of panels in y-direction
        for (int b = 0; b < nudSizeY.Value; b++)
        {
            allRows.Add(null);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nudSizeY.Value; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < nudSizeX.Value; j++)
            {
                // new panel is created, random values for background color are assigned, position and size is calculated
                //pnlBack is a panel used as a canvas on whoch the other panels are shown
                Panel pnl = new Panel();
                pnl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size((Convert.ToInt32(pnlBack.Size.Width)) / Convert.ToInt32(nudSizeX.Value), (Convert.ToInt32(pnlBack.Size.Height) / Convert.ToInt32(nudSizeY.Value)));
                pnl.Location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32((j * pnl.Size.Width)), (Convert.ToInt32((i * pnl.Size.Height))));

                //There are different types of panels that vary in color. nudTypesNumber iis the user-chosen value for howmany types there should be.
                int z = r.Next(0, Convert.ToInt32(nudTypesNumber.Value));

                //A user given percentage of the panels shall be free, i.e. white.
                int w = r.Next(0, 100);
                if (w < nudPercentFree.Value)
                {
                    pnl.BackColor = Color.White;

                }
                //If a panel is not free/white, another rendom color is  assigned to it. The random number determinig the Color is storede in int z.
                else
                {
                    switch (z)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            pnl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            pnl.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            pnl.BackColor = Color.Lime;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            pnl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                //Every panel has to be added to a list called horizontal rows. This list is later added to a List<List<Panel>> calles allRows.
                horizontalRows[j] = (pnl);
                //The panel has also to be added to the "canvas-panel" pnl back. The advantage of using the canvas panel is that it is easier to determine the coordinates on this panel then  on the whole form.
                pnlBack.Controls.Add(pnl);
            }
            allRows[i] = horizontalRows;
        }
```

As you might imagine, this is very slow when creating a checkerboard of 99x99 because the program has to loop through the process nearly 10000 times.

What would you to to improve performance? I said I'd like to keep doing it with panels because I'm comfortable with them, but if using panels is even more dumb than I thought, I'm open to other options. The program gets slower and slower the more panels it has already created. I guess that's because of the adding to the list that grows larger and larger?

This is how the output looks right now:
[image: The crossed out parts are not important yet]

This is what I want to do with my "picture" later: I basically want to do Schellings model. That model shows  how different groups of people (i.e. different colors) segregate when they want to have a certain percentage of people around them that belong to their group. That means that later on I have to be able to check for each of the panels/pixels what the neighbours are and have to be able to be able to change color of each pixel individually.

I don't want a ready solution, I'm just hoping for tips how to improve the speed of the picture-creating process.

Thank you very much

Comment: Use GDI+ to draw the pixels on a canvas.

Comment: I don't know GDI+ (I'm a beginner) but I watched a tutorial and it looks good. But how can I can I add my drawn rectangles to a list? Or is that not possible (as I said, I don't know GDI+)?

Comment: You really *really* don't want to do it like that. Each panel is a separate Windows control with its own handle and it will have an enormous overhead! Use a little class wrapper for your rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I suggest you using GDI+ instead , you can store your colors in a 2 dimensional array so you can draw the desired image based on that and also you can loop through them for further process , take a look at this code and also the demo project :

as you mentioned that you're not familiar with gdi+ , there is a demo project included so you can check it yourself and see how It's done in gdi+ :

demo project : [ColorsTableDemoProject](http://www.mehrandavoodi.ir/WindowsFormsApplication28.rar)

```
    Color[,] colorsTable;
    Bitmap b;
    Graphics g;
    int size = 80;  // size of table 
    int pixelWidth = 5; // size of each pixel
    Random r = new Random();
    int rand;

    // CMDDraw is my Form button which draws the image 

    private void CMDDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colorsTable = new Color[size, size];
        pictureBox1.Size = new Size(size * pixelWidth, size * pixelWidth);
        b = new Bitmap(size * pixelWidth, size * pixelWidth);
        g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
            {
                rand = r.Next(0, 4);
                switch (rand)
                {
                    case 0: colorsTable[x, y] = Color.White; break;
                    case 1: colorsTable[x, y] = Color.Red; break;
                    case 2: colorsTable[x, y] = Color.Blue; break;
                    case 3: colorsTable[x, y] = Color.Lime; break;
                    default: break;
                }
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(colorsTable[x, y]), x * pixelWidth, y * pixelWidth, pixelWidth, pixelWidth);
            }
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = b;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Panels` use a matrix to store your colors and other information you need.
In `OnPaint` event, use this matrix to draw the rectangles using `GDI+`.

Here is an example on how to draw 10x10 "pixels" if you have a matrix that contains colors:

```
private void myPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    for (var y=0; y < matrix.GetUpperBound(0); y++)
        for (var x=0; x < matrix.GetUpperBound(1); x++)
        {
            var Brush = new SolidBrush(matrix[y,x]);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush, new Rectangle(x*10, y*10, 10, 10));
        }
}
```

Comment: All right, that is helpful.
What if I want to change the color of an already drawn rectangle? Du I have to create a new one then? Is the old one deleted automatically? Or can I somehow change the color as I would with a panel? (My beloved old panels ;-)

Comment: You just change the color value in the matrix and call Invalidate() on panel which is painting your pixels.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that when I need it. But I somehow can't handle the paint event. I only want to create my picture when a button is clicked, but right now it just creates it when the form is loaded.

Comment: Your paint event should draw your current state. Based on that, in paint event, just clear control if matrix is not yet populated (button not yet clicked). I mean, this is so trivial and common sense that you should not be even asking these kinds of questions.

Comment: To fill (clear) your control with some color, use e.Graphics.Clear(SomeColor);

Answer (score 1):

Use a picturebox to do your drawing. You've already got the code to see where each panel should be, just change it to draw a rectangle at each position. This way, you'll just be drawing a few rectangles on a board instead of working with 10.000 GUI objects.

Oh, keep your model/logic and view separated. Keep one matrix with all your information and just use a "Paint method" to draw it.

Your model could look something like this:

```
MyPanel[,] panels;
class MyPanel
{
  Color color;
}
```

This way it's easy to check all neighbours of a panel, just check in the panels matrix.

And your view should just do something like this:

```
class View
{
  Paint(MyPanel[,] panels)
  {
    //Draw
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best approach here is to write a custom Control class to draw the squares, and a custom collection class to hold the squares.

Your square collection class could look like this:

```
public sealed class ColouredSquareCollection
{
    readonly int _width;
    readonly int _height;
    readonly Color[,] _colours;

    public ColouredSquareCollection(int width, int height)
    {
        _width  = width;
        _height = height;

        _colours = new Color[_width, _height];

        intialiseColours();
    }

    public Color this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return _colours[x, y]; }
        set { _colours[x, y] = value; }
    }

    public int Width
    {
        get { return _width; }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return _height; }
    }

    void intialiseColours()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < _height; ++y)
            for (int x = 0; x < _width; ++x)
                _colours[x, y] = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Then you write a custom control. To do so, add a new Custom control via `Add new item -> Windows Forms -> Custom Control`, and call it `ColouredSquareHolder`.

Then change the code to look like this. Notice how it is responsible for drawing all the squares:

```
public sealed partial class ColouredSquareHolder: Control
{
    ColouredSquareCollection _squares;

    public ColouredSquareHolder()
    {
        ResizeRedraw = true;
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ColouredSquareCollection Squares
    {
        get
        {
            return _squares;
        }

        set
        {
            _squares = value;
            Invalidate();     // Redraw after squares change.
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);

        if (_squares == null)
            return;

        int w = Width;
        int h = Height;
        int nx = _squares.Width;
        int ny = _squares.Height;

        var canvas = pe.Graphics;

        for (int yi = 0; yi < ny; ++yi)
        {
            for (int xi = 0; xi < nx; ++xi)
            {
                int x1 = (xi*w)/nx;
                int dx = ((xi + 1)*w)/nx - x1;
                int y1 = (yi*h)/ny;
                int dy = ((yi+1)*h)/ny - y1;

                using (var brush = new SolidBrush(_squares[xi, yi]))
                    canvas.FillRectangle(brush, x1, y1, dx, dy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you'll need to set up the square collection, add it to a ColouredSquareHolder and then add that to a form.

Firstly, add the ColouredSquareHolder to your test program and compile it so that it will show up in the Toolbox for the Windows Forms Editor.

Then create a new default Form called `Form1`, and from the Toolbox add a `ColouredSquareHolder` to it, and set the `ColouredSquareHolder` to Dock->Fill. Leave it called the default `colouredSquareHolder1` for this demonstration.

Then change your Form1 class to look like this:

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    readonly ColouredSquareCollection _squares;
    readonly Random _rng = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _squares = new ColouredSquareCollection(100, 100);

        for (int x = 0; x < _squares.Width; ++x)
            for (int y = 0; y < _squares.Height; ++y)
                _squares[x, y] = randomColour();

        colouredSquareHolder1.Squares = _squares;
    }

    Color randomColour()
    {
        return Color.FromArgb(_rng.Next(256), _rng.Next(256), _rng.Next(256));
    }
}
```

Run your program and see how much faster it is at drawing the squares.

Hopefully this will give you the basis for something that you can build on.

Note: If you change the colours in the square collection, you will need to call `.Invalidate()` on the control in the form to make it redraw with the new colours.